# Data binding for different attribute types in parent & child components under locker service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

With a lack of documentation I'm trying to understand how data binding works under locker service, when using different types in `<aura:attribute type="...">` to pass values between parent & child components.

Before locker everything worked beautifully, I was able to pass complex type into child component, manipulate it there an still have the same instance in the parent object, which for me enabled nice capabilities of code structuring and decomposition.

Now I know that "Secure Object" proxy is introduced. I've seen numerous questions asked here related to this, but I'd really appreciate if someone can answer what is a bug, and what will be working in target solution.

Below I tried to describe 4 scenarios and my observations. What I did are two simple components - parent and child. Parent has one attribute, passed to child. Child component has input field that allow to modify this attribute. This is how it looks:

[image]

**Test 1 - Strings**

For Strings, everything seems to work fine. `Console.log` displays proper value for both parent & child components. Binding seems to be done live. When you type in value in child component `inputText`, it's displayed live in the parent component output: `Parent: {!v.testAtr}`

Parent Component

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="testAtr" type="String" access="global"/>

   Parent: {!v.testAtr} <a onclick="{!c.logTestAtr}">LOG PARENT</a>
   <br></br><br></br>
   <c:childCmp testAtr="{!v.testAtr}"/>

</aura:component>
```

Parent Component Controller:

```
logTestAtr : function(component) {
    console.log(component.get("v.testAtr"));
}
```

Child Component

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="testAtr" type="String" access="global"/>

   child: <ui:inputText value="{!v.testAtr}"/>  
   <a onclick="{!c.logTestAtr}">LOG CHILD</a>

</aura:component>
```

Child Component Controller:

```
logTestAtr : function(component) {
    console.log(component.get("v.testAtr"));
}
```

**Test 2 - Maps (with default value)**

For Maps, when you specify default value for data attribute - almost all works exactly like for strings, but the data binding in the parent component is not actualized when you change value in child component. So in child inputText you have 'test', when you change it to 'test2' console.log from parent will show you 'test2', but output: `Parent: {!v.testAtr}` will still show old 'test' value.

Parent Component

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="testAtr" type="Map" default="'data': 'test'" access="global"/>

   Parent: {!v.testAtr.data} <a onclick="{!c.logTestAtr}">LOG PARENT</a>
   <br></br><br></br>
   <c:childCmp testAtr="{!v.testAtr}"/>

</aura:component>
```

Parent Component Controller:

```
logTestAtr : function(component) {
    console.log(component.get("v.testAtr").data);
}
```

Child Component

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="testAtr" type="Map" access="global"/>

   child: <ui:inputText value="{!v.testAtr.data}"/>  
   <a onclick="{!c.logTestAtr}">LOG CHILD</a>

</aura:component>
```

Child Component Controller:

```
logTestAtr : function(component) {
    console.log(component.get("v.testAtr").data);
}
```

**Test 3 - Maps (without setting default value)**

Now, what happens if you don't specify `default="'data': 'test'"` in the parent attribute, just `default="{}"` to avoid null pointer? Console.log from both parent & child are showing `undefined`, even after putting the value into inputText.

Parent Component

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="testAtr" type="Map" default="{}" access="global"/>

   Parent: {!v.testAtr.data} <a onclick="{!c.logTestAtr}">LOG PARENT</a>
   <br></br><br></br>
   <c:childCmp testAtr="{!v.testAtr}"/>

</aura:component>
```

Parent Component Controller:

```
logTestAtr : function(component) {
    console.log(component.get("v.testAtr").data);
}
```

Child Component

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="testAtr" type="Map" access="global"/>

   child: <ui:inputText value="{!v.testAtr.data}"/>  
   <a onclick="{!c.logTestAtr}">LOG CHILD</a>

</aura:component>
```

Child Component Controller:

```
logTestAtr : function(component) {
    console.log(component.get("v.testAtr").data);
}
```

**Test 4 - Objects**

Now - the same case as Test 2 - but we use `type="Object"` now. I would expect simillar behavior as Map, but here - I get `undefined` all the times in `console.log`

Parent Component

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="testAtr" type="Object" default="'data': 'test'" access="global"/>

   Parent: {!v.testAtr.data} <a onclick="{!c.logTestAtr}">LOG PARENT</a>
   <br></br><br></br>
   <c:childCmp testAtr="{!v.testAtr}"/>

</aura:component>
```

Parent Component Controller:

```
logTestAtr : function(component) {
    console.log(component.get("v.testAtr").data);
}
```

Child Component

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="testAtr" type="Object" access="global"/>

   child: <ui:inputText value="{!v.testAtr.data}"/>  
   <a onclick="{!c.logTestAtr}">LOG CHILD</a>

</aura:component>
```

Child Component Controller:

```
logTestAtr : function(component) {
    console.log(component.get("v.testAtr").data);
}
```

I'd appreciate if somebody can comment on this, or at least direct me to some further reading.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me .Did you open a case ?

Answer (score 3):

I think that after spending few hours I found the answer for the above. Still not sure if it's a bug or a feature of the framework, but definately it has something to do with how secure objects are constructed.

You need to make sure all possible properties for the object are defined (even if null) when you call `component.set("v.obj", obj);` for the first time.

Here is example component & controller, with one simple attribute (initialized on init), and two buttons calling log & set functions of controller:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="testAtr" type="Object" access="global"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initialize}"/>
    <p><a onclick="{!c.logAtr}">Console Log Parent</a></p>
    <p><a onclick="{!c.setSth}">Set Something</a></p>
</aura:component>

({
    initialize : function(component, event, helper) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.data = 'test';
        // obj.someNewProperty = null;
        component.set("v.testAtr", obj);
    },
    logAtr : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(component.get("v.testAtr.someNewProperty"));
    },
    setSth : function(component, event, helper) {
        var testAtr = component.get("v.testAtr");
        testAtr.someNewProperty = 'New Property';
        component.set("v.testAtr", testAtr);
    },
})
```

If the line `obj.someNewProperty = null;` in `initialize` method is commented out, `console.log` returns `undefined` even if you call `setSth` method that actually sets value of `obj.someNewProperty`.

If the line `obj.someNewProperty = null;` in `initialize` method is present, `console.log` returns null before calling `setSth` method and `'New Property'` after calling it.

**EDIT:**
But this has some drawbacks. Let's imagine we have a simple form for sObject. You need to initialize object with all the possible properties. If you don't do this - no values will be kept. If these lines: `acc.Name = null; acc.Phone = null; acc.Account_Status__c = null;` are commented as in below example - value put in the input text is not bind to `testAcc` attribute.

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="testAcc" type="Account" access="global"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initialize}"/>

    <p>Name: <ui:inputText value="{!v.testAcc.Name}"/></p>
    <p>Phone: <ui:inputText value="{!v.testAcc.Phone}"/></p>
    <p>Status: <ui:inputText value="{!v.testAcc.Account_Status__c}"/></p>
    <p><a onclick="{!c.logAcc}">Console Log Acc</a></p>
</aura:component>

({
    initialize : function(component, event, helper) {
        var acc = {};
        // acc.Name = null;
        // acc.Phone = null;
        // acc.Account_Status__c = null;
        component.set("v.testAcc", acc);
    },

    logAcc : function(component) {
        console.log(component.get("v.testAcc"));
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive investigation. There is a bug for requiring all possible properties to be defined at object initialization. If you open a case you can link to internal work item W-3221032.

For scenarios where you can't define all properties up front, you can try this temporary hack to stringify/parse your object after adding the new property to force it through the LockerService filtering logic: `component.set("v.testAtr", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(testAtr)))`

Comment: Thanks @Trevor, I opened a case for that. Do you by any chance know when it may be resolved?

Comment: This is scheduled to be fixed in the Summer '17 release. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting things happen around the type attribute; I used to think it had to hold the object API name -like type="Project__c[]"- but this is causes some interesting behavior people might want to know about. 
I've experimented with this variable and found this:

1. type="FooBar[]"                    > FAIL
2. type="object[]" / type="sObject[]" > OK
3. type="Project__c[]" > This is interesting; I found that when you use the API name as type with an admin profile, it's perfectly fine but when you access the page with a profile that doesn't have access to the object used ('Project__c') this wil FAIL...
   And unfortunately you can't capture that failure to use it as a validation method.

Comment: This was very helpful, I was struggling with defining a default object, didn't work. But with Object[] it worked, thanks!